Using non-confirmable CoAP messages and Thingsboard
I am using Thingsboard with CoAP for a low bandwidth IoT solution. All the RPC messages it sends are CONFIRMABLE CoAP messages. I would like it to send NON-CONFIRMABLE ones. Using the 'one-way' tag does not appear to make a difference.
In addition, all the telemetry I send it is NON-CONFIRMABLE, but Thingsboard still feels the need to send an acknowledgement. Is there a setting somewhere to prevent this?
I have gone through the git source and the californium source code looking for references to it. It appears to be an option if I were using LwM2M instead of CoAP? However I am not.
I also looked at the meta-data for packets coming in at the rule chain, but do not see any obvious switches I can use to make the messages NON-CONFIRMABLE.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I don't think, that the lack of more answers is the result of an unclear question. It's more caused by the required expertise, which is pretty rare. It then also requires some more knowledge of the device/client implementation and all-in-all, using one-way messages isn't easy, but also doesn't provide really the expected benefit, at least not with cellular communication.

NON messages are only half of the "one-way" topic.
For RFC 7252 (CoAP core) usually, if a request is sent, a response is expected. That applies also for a NON request. Only for NON responses the result is a "one-way" message. In the past the work-around (also used in LwM2M) was to use the observer/notify (RFC7641) and then send the data in responses (notifications) as NON messages.
In our days RFC 7967 "Option No Server Response" may be used to send NON requests also as real "one-way" message.

In addition, all the telemetry I send it is NON-CONFIRMABLE, but Thingsboard still feels the need to send an acknowledgement. Is there a setting somewhere to prevent this?

If your telemetry data is sent as NON request, you still get a response for it, unless you use the "No Server Response Option".

I have gone through the git source and the californium source code looking for references to it.

References for what? The term "one-way"? If you help me with, what you searched for and how, I may add that to Californium in a way that the next will have a chance to find it ;-).
Let me finish:
I'm not sure, what you really want to do and what you consider to be required.
Just as an example, my Zephyr-coaps-client runs on a Thingy:91 from battery for 6-12 months exchanging a message every hour.
One-way may in the end not help too much. But will bring some uncertainness.
